# Foreign key constraint cannot be implemented Error

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I have two entities Permission and Roles, and need to develop a relation between them where Roles can reference multiple permissions.

**Permission Entity**

```
@Entity({ schema: 'permissions' })
export class Permission {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: number

  @Column({ length: 50 })
  name: string
}
```

**Role Entity**

```
@Entity({ schema: 'permissions', name: 'roles' })
export class Role {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: number

  @Column({ length: 50 })
  name: string

  @Column({ nullable: false, array: true, type: 'integer' })
  @ManyToOne(() => Permission)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'permissions' })
  permissions: Permission[]
}
```

The permissions column in Role table needs to reference the id of the Permission table  something like [1,2,.]
I have added a @ManyToOne() relation here, but this is resulting in an error `QueryFailedError: foreign key constraint "FK_FK_f17d00f744c3a2f4923d1d64665" cannot be implemented`